# PostgreSQL JDBC sink raise error null(Array) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have problem when try to replicate my database using Kafka JDBC sink. When I run my server to a table which has Array data type on it, it give this error

```
...
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: null (ARRAY) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type
...
```

I want to retain the same Array condition and don't want to convert it into string like what i do to SQL Server (since SQL Server not allowed array data type).

This is my connection config:

```
{"name" :"pgsink_'$topic_name'",
    "config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
            "tasks.max":"1",
            "topics":"'$table'",
            "connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://",
            "connection.user":"",
            "connection.password":"",
            "transforms":"unwrap",
            "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
            "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
            "delete.handling.mode":"drop",
            "auto.create":"true",
            "auto.evolve":"true",
            "insert.mode":"upsert",
            "pk.fields":" '$pk'",
            "pk.mode":"record_key",
            "delete.enabled":"true",
            "destination.table.format":"public.'$table'",
            "connection.attempts":"60",
            "connection.backoff.ms":"100000"

}}
```

My Kafka source came from Debezium, since I want to retain same data type, i don't put SMT into my source. This is the source config:

```
{
"name":"pg_prod",
    "config":{
        "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "plugin.name":"wal2json_streaming",
        "database.hostname":"",
        "database.port":"",
        "database.user":"",
        "database.password":"",
        "database.dbname":"",
        "database.server.name":"",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "",
        "transforms":"unwrap,reroute",
    "table.whitelist":"public.table",
    "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "drop",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "decimal.handling.mode":"double",
        "time.precision.mode":"connect",
    "transforms.reroute.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.reroute.regex":"postgres.public.(.*)",
    "transforms.reroute.replacement":"$1",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
        "errors.log.enable":true,
        "errors.log.include.messages":true,
    "kafkaPartition": "0",
    "snapshot.delay.ms":"1000",
    "schema.refresh.mode":"columns_diff_exclude_unchanged_toast"
    }
}
```

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you manage to fing a solution?

Comment: I am seeing this issue, did anyone find a solution to the problem?